# Tomcat specific webapp slowdown

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, windows-server-2012-r2

Today in the company where I work we received a report about one of our webapps not working.

The first thing we did was look at the hardware utilization:

- Processor: 5%;
- Memory: 68%;
- Disk IO capacity: 4%;
- Network: 1Mbps/1Gbps;

After some tests we saw that, indeed, the webapp pages weren't loading, some time after the webapp timeouts.

Other webapps in the exactly same tomcat instance were working fine and fast as ever, no problem with them. We tried to restart/reload the webapp but it still didn't get it working. Finally we restarted tomcat which corrected the issue for now.

There were no restarts or redeploys since yesterday when it was working fine. We believe this may be a periodic bug of some sort so we want to correct it soon.

Does anyone know of any steps we may take to investigate what it might have been?

Comment: a) Check logs for disk space exhaustion or bottlenecks somewhere else; b) Check the server stats over time (resource monitor or similar) and check if disk is not full; c) If no probable cause, run it NOT IN PRODUCTION and profile the webapp using Java Mission Control. Did I mention not to do it in production environment? (license stuff)

Comment: a) Disk space is plenty ( 50GB).
b) Stats over time not shows anything strage or uncommon.
c) Will try in our dev enviroment.

Comment: d) check on localhost_...log in /logs, see what's the server's response for those faulty requests and compare with server.log at that time.

Comment: d) main responses where 2xx or 3xx.

Comment: Do you know if requests were actually getting to the webapp? If main responses were 2xx, 3xx, incoming requests could have been dropped before being queued. Check on your browser... also, do you have something in between, network-related?

Comment: The responses where 2xx and 3xx on server side so the requests weren't dropped by the server and rather by the browser. Between the browser and the server, yes this specific server is hosted in a cloud.

The webapp works well in the dev team machines or in our internal dev server.

Comment: Check database connections. See if the every connection is released.

Comment: Too bad you bounced the container, otherwise you might have been able to determine the cause of the problem. Now that it's no longer reproducible, you have little chance of finding and fixing the root issue. Next time, collect more information before you restart the service. For example, take a few thread dumps to find out what the JVM is doing when you try to access your application.

Comment: Thanks, Christopher, i will try to get better information if it happens a next time. Do you have any suggestions of what we may look for to determine the root issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems related to lock on IO.

If you are using linux, **the first** thing is do is to check open files by using the command **lsof** . If you see a lot of opened files by your app, you have to check in the code that every InputStream/OutputStream are closed (even in exception handling code).

An other common source of issues is related to thread starvation, see **http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Stuck_Thread_Detection_Valve**

Comment: At least from Find Bugs there are no unclosed input/output streams. I agree it looks like a deadlock.

Comment: see **lsof** to be sure of that.